# I'm making a donut chart with HTML and CSS, need help placing my spans in the middle of the wedges

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Pretty much I'm making a half a donut chart. Found some code on the internet but it doesn't really do it the way I want. It uses `<ul>` and `<li>` and borders, also uses animation to fill the chart up.

I've tried giving it a margin-left and yes it goes inside de chart but to get it in the middle is really hard.

```css
.chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 25rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chart::before,
.chart::after {
  position: absolute;
}

.chart::before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 5rem solid rgba(211, 211, 211, .3);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 25rem;
}

.chart::after {
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.chart li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 5rem solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25rem;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.chart li:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 11;
    border-color: rgb(197, 8, 8);
    animation-name: rotate-one;
}

.chart li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 10;
    border-color: rgb(11, 139, 245);
    animation-name: rotate-two;
    animation-delay: .4s;
}

.chart li:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 9;
    border-color: rgb(216, 116, 23);
    animation-name: rotate-three;
    animation-delay: .8s;
}

.chart li:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 8;
    border-color: rgb(92, 197, 89);
    animation-name: rotate-four;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

/* ..... here is the span or text i want centered */

.chart li span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.85rem;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    /**/
    color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: -2.25em;
    text-align: center;
}

.chart li:nth-child(1) span {
    transform: rotate(-59.65714285714286deg);
}

.chart li:nth-child(2) span {
    transform: rotate(-98.22857142857143deg);
    animation-delay: .4s;      
}

.......... this is the animations that the wedges/borders do

@keyframes rotate-one {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(59.65714285714286deg);
    /**
     * 12% => 21.6deg
     */
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-two {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(59.65714285714286deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(98.22857142857143deg);
    /**
     * 32% => 57.6deg 
     * 57.6 + 21.6 => 79.2deg
     */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="chart">
    <li>
        <span>116</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>75</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>47</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>44</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>38</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
<ul>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTwMu.png)

Comment: Can you share your desired result? How it should look!

Comment: yes, i added it now.